# bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(img) command not working properly

Tags: python

I am using the following command for object detection

```py
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(img)
```

but it returns 0 for all three output parameters.I have tried multiple images and there's no issue with the code. I am using the code available everywhere and it seems to work for everyone else. Can someone help? I am attaching a screenshot of what values I get. Please have a look. [values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKNBM.png)

Answer (score 0):

`cv.detect_common_objects(img)` uses [Yolov3](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) model trained on [Coco dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#home). This dataset contains 80 objects.

Can you check if your image has one of these objects. Here is the [link](https://github.com/amikelive/coco-labels/blob/master/coco-labels-2014_2017.txt) for the list of objects.

Comment: Yes, all objects in my images are in this list.

Comment: Can you check if the image is not empty before passing to `cv.detect_common_objects(img)`?

Comment: Or if you have a Mac, it might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/cvlib/issues/27). Anyway I'd suggest you'll find more help on this [issue page](https://github.com/arunponnusamy/cvlib/issues).

Comment: No, I have checked. The image is not empty.